# add and position text to sankeyNetwork using htmlwidgets

Tags: r

I am struggling to make modification to html widget produced with `sankeyNetwork`  function.

Say that `SD` is the output of the function `SankeyDiagram()` so that `dput(SD)` returns the values [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T9nOpjDBOFxlR_RAvwShmKv-5pkdibjO).
`colorJS`  is the following vector:

```
> colorJS
[1] "d3.scaleOrdinal([\" #1f77b4\", \"#aec7e8\", \"#ff7f0e\", \"#ffbb78\", \"#008800\", \"#ff9900\", \"#aaaaaa\", \"#ffcc33\", \"#548235\", \"#00CC00\", \"#203864\", \"#315597\", \"##5A82CA\", \"#3399ff\", \"#33ccff\", \"#999999\", \"#9467bd\", \"#c5b0d5\", \"#8c564b\", \"#c49c94\", \"#e377c2\", \"#f7b6d2\", \"#7f7f7f\", \"#c7c7c7\", \"#bcbd22\", \"#dbdb8d\", \"#17becf\", \"#9edae5\", \"#1f77b4\", \"#aec7e8\", \"#ff7f0e\", \"#ffbb78\", \"#008800 \"])"
```

to create a  sankeyNetwork I do the following:

```
sankey <- sankeyNetwork(SD$links,SD$nodes,Source = 'source', Target = 'target', Value = 'value', 
NodeID = 'name', sinksRight = FALSE, fontSize = 21, fontFamily = "Verdana", LinkGroup = 'group', NodeGroup = 'group', colourScale =colorJS, nodeWidth = 20, nodePadding = 20 ,                            iterations=0 , margin = list(top=-250, right=-700, left=-400, bottom=150))

    # add title and text   
    sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$h1(paste0('Country Group: ', country,';  Year: ',sYear0[y] )))
    sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::tags$h2('Gases', 'Sectors', 'Stages', 'Categories') )
```

I would like to achieve that the content in the widget (Gases, Sectors, Stages, CAtegoroes) to be vertically aligned with the stages of the diagrams, like in the figure[image: sankey diagram] like some sort of x-axis.

Can this be achieved with htmlwidgets (or any other trick)?
many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out by using:

```
htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::includeMarkdown("group.txt"))
```

where 'group.txt' contains the `&nbsp;` string repeated multiple times to produce blank spaces.

Not an elegant solution, but does the job.

Comment: Hello. Could you specify what the "group.txt" file looks like ? I tried with &nbsp; repeated different times but it just added a blank between the h2 tag and the Sankey plot, not between the h2 contents (Gases, Sectors, Stages, Categories). Also where in the code did you use that command ? (htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey, htmltools::includeMarkdown("group.txt"))
Thanks a lot

Comment: hi, I just looked at your comment, don't know if still useful but there you go: ````&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font size="5"> **GASES** </font> &nbsp;  ```` etc... It is the very last command of the script: ````sankey <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(sankey1, htmltools::includeMarkdown("group.txt"))
    sankey ````